# how to apply jquery nested on a table inside a div?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, nested, datalist

I have a div with id="container" and a datalist is inside that div and css class is box now i want to make the data items like bricks in the wall by using jquery nested plugin here is the link http://suprb.com/apps/nested/ . Can anybody help me out with this?
here is the code snippet

```
<div id="container">         
    <asp:DataList CssClass="box slider_container" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" ID="kiosk_grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="kiosk_grid_dsource" ShowHeader="false" ShowFooter="false">
        <ItemTemplate>       
            <a class="slider_container" href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/kioskstore.aspx/?name=")%><%#Eval("kiosk_Name")%>'>        
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Kiosk_Image") %>' />
            </a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready (function () {
        $("#container").nested ({ selector: '.box' });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Nested plugin is doing the layout there's no reason to have the data in a table in the first place, and if you swap your DataList for a Repeater you can render your items without a table getting in the way. You'll need to wrap your template content in a div for the plugin to target, and if you give it the default class "box" you needn't specify that selector in the script.

So you'd have:

```
<div id="container">
    <asp:Repeater ID="kiosk_grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="kiosk_grid_dsource">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="box">
                <a class="slider_container" href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/kioskstore.aspx/?name=")%><%#Eval("kiosk_Name")%>'>
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Kiosk_Image") %>' /></a>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#container").nested();
    });
</script>
```